# Listing the most recently uploaded artifacts in Artifactory

Tags: rest, maven, artifactory

Is there a programmatic way to list the most recently uploaded artifacts in [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview), using its [REST API](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API)?

For example, my Artifactory setup has 6 local repositories hosting our in-house built artifacts and 8 remote repositories act as mirrors of some public maven repositories.

And I would like to get a list of in-house build artifacts that were uploaded to those 6 local repositories in last few hours, days or week, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [artifacts created in date range](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#Artifactory%27sRESTAPI-ArtifactsCreatedinDateRange) REST query. It does exactly what you're after and you can limit the search to specific repos.

Comment: New Link: http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactsCreatedinDateRange

Comment: is it possible to parameter which artifact?